# NoMethodError for nested images via Paperclip

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I get an error when trying to save / view a picture into / from a nested table. I want to store multiple photos that belong to one blog, hence the nested set-up.

Several answers to similar questions on SO didn't lead me to the solutions.

The error:

*NoMethodError in Blogs#show
Showing /home/ubuntu/workspace/MyDashboard/app/views/blogs/show.html.erb where line #11 raised:
undefined method `photo' for #*

I don't think the picture is saved at all, and/or the "photo" attribute it not known.

**Blog.rb:**

```
class Blog < ApplicationRecord

  validates_presence_of :date, :story

  has_many :blog_images, :dependent => :destroy
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :blog_images, reject_if: :all_blank, allow_destroy: true
end
```

**Blog_Image.rb**

```
class BlogImage < ApplicationRecord

  belongs_to :blog

  has_attached_file :photo, :styles => { :small => "150x150>", :large => "320x240>" }
  validates_attachment_content_type :photo, :content_type => /\Aimage\/.*\z/

end
```

**Routes.db:**

```
  resources :blogs do
    resources :blog_images
  end
```

**Controller:**

```
  def new
    @blog = Blog.new
    @blog.blog_images.build
  end

  def create
    @blog = Blog.new(blog_params)

    if @blog.save
      redirect_to blogs_path
    else
      render 'new'
    end
  end
(...)

  private

    def blog_params
      params.require(:blog).permit(:story, :date,
                            blog_images_attributes: [:id, :blog_id, :photo])
    end
```

**Input form:**

```
<%= form_for(@blog, :html => {:multipart => true}) do |f| %>

  <div class="field">
    <%= f.label :date %>
    <%= f.date_field :date %>
  </div>

  <div class="field">
    <%= f.label :story %>
    <%= f.text_area :story %>
  </div>

  <%=f.fields_for :blog_images do |i| %>
    <%= i.file_field :photo %>
  <% end %>

  <div class="actions">
    <%= f.submit %>
  </div>

<% end %>
```

**View:**

```
  <p>
    <%= image_tag @blog.blog_images.photo.url(:small) %>
  </p>
```

The form is saving but when I want to view it, I get the above error. I'd appreciate your help!

Answer (score 0):

```
@blog.blog_images
```

is a collection of images. See `has_many :blog_images` in `class Blog`

The collection doesn't know the method `photo`, even though every element of this collection knows it. What's the capital of `['USA', 'UK', 'Germany']` ?

You need to iterate with

```
<% @blog.blog_images.each do |blog_image| %>
 <p>
    <%= image_tag blog_image.photo.url(:small) %>
  </p>
<% end %>
```

Comment: Thank you Eric, this solved my error for the view file indeed. Now I'm stuck with the next one (which I'd already expected): there hasn't been added a photo added at all, as the form renders :new again. Does my form with nested attribute contain an error as far as you can see?
I tested the paperclip-model without a nested table for photos and got it to work easily.